# Preventing COM Name Mangling

Tags: c#, com, vb6, interop, legacy-code

I am trying to write a replacement for a VB6 dll that is referenced by another VB6 in c#.net.

For now we can only work on the later and I am having some success with this. Except I have run into a problem.

My Enums are being mangling resulting it being called 'A1BACSTrans_BACSAU' instead of the expect 'BACSAU'

the legacy code will (obviously) no longer compile.

Can this be prevented? if so, how? I have heard of modifying the IDL but I can see no references in their to a mangled name only unmangled...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which IDL are you looking at then?

Comment: .class public auto ansi sealed TestA1Replacement.BCStrategy
       extends [mscorlib]System.Enum
{
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute::.ctor(bool) = ( 01 00 01 00 00 )
  .field public specialname rtspecialname int32 value__
  .field public static literal valuetype TestA1Replacement.BCStrategy BCStratAV = int32(0x00000000)
........ more.......
} // end of class TestA1Replacement.BCStrategy

I can see no evidence of name mangling in the above.

Comment: @Mattias OK.

I think that was 'il' not 'idl' and hence did not carry what I was expecting.

I have since sound this from using OLE/COM Object Viewer.

    enum {
        BCStrategy_BCStratAV = 0,
        BCStrategy_BCStratFull = 1,
        BCStrategy_BCStratInfo = 2,
        BCStrategy_BCStratNone = 3
    } BCStrategy;

However when I save and try and use Midl to create a tbl i get loads of errors

: error MIDL2088 : [uuid] format is incorrect

is there really no way to say at the code level not to mangle these names?!

Comment: Guys, I have been discussing this over at c-sharpcorner also and although I mainly arrived at the solution myself I have document it there. 

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/111642/preventing-com-name-mangling.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Guys, I have been discussing this over at c-sharpcorner also and although I mainly arrived at the solution myself I have document it there

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/111642/preventing-com-name-mangling.aspx

Basically changing the IDL is the way I found to do it.

I'd love to know if there is a way to do it in code, maybe an attribute but if there is a way I don't know it!